# ¿Cómo exporto filas especificas de una consulta utilizando checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo una consulta con una tabla que tiene una columna de checkboxes, los cuales tienen como propiedad value, los ids de los artículos, y un botón de descarga, para bajar la base de datos y una plantilla para un software de escritorio.

El problema surge de querer descargar la base de datos, con artículos específicos solamente, y por eso se me ocurrió utilizar checkboxes, donde el usuario pudiera descargar la base de datos con los artículos que requiriera solamente.

No he trabajado mucho con estos escenarios, pero vi un video de como enviar múltiples valores de checkbox utilizando una lista (por ello, incluí esto en la funcion: $ids = implode(', ', $ids);) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jx4qVolKkJQ

El motivo de este post fue que no podía realizar ninguna accion, si alguno de los 2 archivos que necesito se descarga, y por eso pensé en abrirlo en una nueva pestaña y continuar con la exportación, por ejemplo.

Esa fue la solución que se me ocurrió y tal vez si me estoy complicando más...

//tabla

```
<form id="impresion"action="descargar.php" method="post">
<div style="text-align: right"><a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('impresion').submit();"><img src="imagenes/plantilla.png" title=Descargar&nbsp;datos width=30 height=25/></a></div>
<div>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="auto"><INPUT type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)"/></td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>y</td>
            <td>z</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" name="chkbox[]"value="1"/></td>
            <td>a1</td>
            <td>a2</td>
            <td>a3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" name="chkbox[]"value="2"/></td>
            <td>b1</td>
            <td>b2</td>
            <td>b3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" name="chkbox[]"value="3"/></td>
            <td>c1</td>
            <td>c2</td>
            <td>c3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" name="chkbox[]"value="4"/></td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d2</td>
            <td>d3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</form>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function toggle(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('chkbox[]');
            for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;

            }
        }
    </SCRIPT>
```

//archivo de descarga

```
<?php
  ob_start();
?>
<?php 
if($_POST['chkbox'] =="" ) {
    //exit();
    header("location:consulta.php");
}
echo '<script>window.open("miarchivo.lbx","_blank")</script>';

// tested with success
$db_name     = "db";
$db_password = "pass";
$db_link     = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", $db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_link);
mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

$where = '';
   if(isset($_POST['chkbox'])){
     $data = implode(',',$_POST['chkbox']); // beacuse your rating is only one column in db i think
     $where = "WHERE id_articulo IN($data)";
   }
$table = "articulos";
function assoc_query_2D($sql, $id_name = false){
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $arr = array();
  $row = array();
  if($result){
    if($id_name == false){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        $arr[] = $row;
    }else{
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $arr[$id] = $row;
      }
    }
  }else
      return 0;

  return $arr;
}
function query_whole_table($where, $value = '*'){
    $sql = "SELECT $value FROM articulos $where";
  return assoc_query_2D($sql);
}
$export_str = '"Id","Nombre","Descripcion","Proveedor","Cantidad","Numero de serie","Categoria","id_pedido","id_usuario","Empresa","Ubicacion","Codigo de barras"'."\n";
$result = query_whole_table($table);

foreach($result as $record){
  $export_str .= '"'.implode('","',$record) .'"'."\n";
}
// output the file 
// we can set a header to send it directly to the browser
file_put_contents($table.".csv", $export_str);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');   
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\""."articulos.csv"."\"");  
echo $export_str; exit;
header("location:miarchivo.lbx");
?>
<?php
  ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es poder descargar más de un archivo, ¿no?

Comment: Si, pero tambien saber por que cuando mi funcion query_whole_table no recibe los valores de checkbox marcados

Comment: Én el código anterior `$ids` no se estaba instanciando y por eso fallaría la select, y en el código actual el `$where` contiene el nombre de la tabla y no la clausula where

Comment: Pero $where contiene id_articulos, que es una columna

Comment: A la variable `$table` se le asigna el valor "articulos" y dicho valor no cambia en el código mostrado. Cuando se llama a la función `query_whole_table` se le pasa la variable `$table` (que dentro de la función se llama `$where`) y con ella se monta la sentencia SQL así: `$sql = "SELECT $value FROM articulos $where";`. En esa asignación, `$value` es `*`, y `$table` es `articulos`, por lo que la sentencia acaba siendo `SELECT * FROM articulos articulos`, que es incorrecta y fallará

Comment: Pero ese no es el fallo por el que no se pueden descargar dos ficheros. Ese es otro asunto, porque como retrasas la escritura (al usar `ob_start`) el `echo` que descargaría el primer archivo nunca se manda al navegador. Esto se debe a que antes de que pueda escribirse el buffer (con `ob_end_flush`) se hace una redirección con `header`.

Comment: ok, ya revise mi funcion y tienes razon, estaba mandando mal los parametros, gracias!

Comment: Revisa también los id's de los checkbox, ¡son los mismos para todos, y eso está mal!

Answer (score 0):

El problema podría estar en el javascript a la hora de querer tomar el valor de los checkboxes, en vez de poner:

```
checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('chkbox[]');
```

podrías poner:

```
checkboxes=$('input[name=chkbox]:checked').val();
```

Comment: el OP no esta utilizando `jquery`, así que no podría ser una respuesta valida o aceptada